# Delay STATE change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, react-hooks

I'm writing a website. It's a website that uses and fetches data from a stock API to displays stock prices and charts.

I have a search bar which changes state whenever a letter is typed in.. However, it's causing problems because it's instantly updating the state, which then fetches data from the API, and if for example I type in Z - then the API is instalty looking for a stock named "Z"
and the app crashes, goes blank ( because such link doesnt exist ). I literally have to copy the stock name like "AAPL" for example and then paste it - for the app to work properly.

```
  var baseUrl = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${search}&apikey=**********`;
```

because state of "search" is updated and it's searching for that stock/

Anyways, here's my stock search bar component.

```
const StockSearchBar = () => {

  const { search, setSearch } = useContext(SearchContext); // i'm using context API to store state so I  can access it across different components

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (setSearch !== '') { // if there's something in state, then post data to backend

      const options = 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({search}),
      };
  
      const response = fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/search`, options);
    };

  function handleButtonEvents(e) { // i'm using a function to chain handleClick() and setTimeout() to be run when button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
        handleClick();
    setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 3000); // delay the function for 3 seconds to give it time to fetch the data and display it, otherwise it might refresh the page without updating it with new data
    }

  const handleSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase()); // i think the problem is here - i need to delay setting state
  }



  return (
      <>
    <div className="searchBar">
      <label>Look for Stocks or Cryptos: </label>
      <input  type='text' onChange={handleSearch} onKeyPress={(ev) => {
        if (ev.key === "Enter") { handleButtonEvents(); }}} 

{/* search if Enter key is pressed */} // i think the problem is with **onChange** or the handleSearch **function** but not sure how to deal with it

      placeholder={search} required />
      <Button variant="success" type="submit" onClick={handleButtonEvents}  >Search</Button>
    </div>
    <h1 className="src">{search}</h1> 
{// display state to see if it's changing ( just testing }
    </>
  );
};

export default StockSearchBar;
```

Let me know if you want to see the context API file, or something else. But I think the probem is in the search bar component.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: It seems like you probably need to `await` that fetch and only then set the state, no? Otherwise, you are just updating the component as soon as handleSearch runs, which is whenever the input text is changed.

Comment: If the desired behaviour is to update the state whenever the search input is updated, the code seems like it should work. You have to consider the impact in other components of doing so. Your issue seems to be related with that. You can either delay the state change by using `setTimeout` and cancelling the timeout when new data is received (basically debouncing the event), or do this in the component that uses the shared state to request data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to use `Debounce` in order to create a delay e.g. from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce). so in your case it would be

```js
  const handleSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    debounce(setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase()), 500)// debounce 500 milliseconds
  }
```